# What changes should be done in the algorithm/ MATLAB code to detect vehicles in proper shape?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, motion-detection

I am working on a project in image processing which is based on importance of phase only reconstruction of a signal obtained using Fourier transform.For more information about phase only reconstruction,you can see the answer given by geometrikal in the [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/how-moving-part-pixel-intensity-values-of-video-frames-becomes-dominant-compared).

Now ,I have detected moving objects from the [video of Traffic on road taken using stationary camera](https://signal642.shutterfly.com/pictures/8) ( Please download  the 1.47 MB video for testing MATLAB Code by ( step1) **click on the play button** then (step2) right clicking on video then ( step3 ) click on save as option )

Algorithm No. 1
The proposed approach

Requirement: An input image sequence I(x, y, n) (where x and y are image dimensions and n represent frame number in a video) which is extracted from video.

Outcome: The segmentation mask of moving object for each frame

> 1. For each frame in a input video perform step 2, append step 2 result in resultant array ‘I(x, y, n)’
> 2. Smoothen the current frame using 2D Gaussian filter
> 3. Perform 3D FFT for the whole sequence I(x, y, n) using [(Eq.4.1)](http://it.thislife.com/exzPhP)
> 4. Calculate the phase spectrum using the real and imaginary parts of 3D DFT
> 5. Calculate the reconstructed sequence Î(x, y, n) using (Eq.4.2)
> 6. For each frame in a input video perform step 7 to step 10 to get segmentation mask for each frame and append step 10 result in resultant segmentation mask array BW(x,y,n)’
> 7. Smooth the reconstructed frame of Î(x, y, n) using the averaging filter.
> 8. Compute the mean value of the current frame
> 9. Convert the current frame into binary image using mean value as the threshold
> 10. Perform morphological processing, i.e., filling and closing, to obtain segmented mask of moving objects for the current frame
> 11. End algorithm.

If you run my MATLAB code, you can observe that I am quite successful in detecting all the moving objects in each video frames. But now I want to detect **only one** moving object at a time from current frame and **avoid other moving objects** by making changes in the **same code or algorithm** .But  don't understand how it can be done.

so can anybody tell me

What changes should be done in the algorithm/ MATLAB code to do **single** vehicle tracking ?

**NOTE : If you are getting problems to reach to links for equation4.1 and equation4.2 of algorithm, please follow the equations from the [paper](http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/mas/article/viewFile/3760/3382&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwigh8DurMXMAhXHMz4KHciTCHUQFggQMAA&sig2=4TPoEYU5j1xFPLogMWBBlg&usg=AFQjCNE6sT8fCig__PDcAxWpTtuU3W5IrQ)**

**UPDATE:** As per Hugh Sir's suggestion, i should try to label the moving object so that tracking is possible. **But while labelling the main difficulty is : after running the above MATLAB code, one will see that the segmented frames which I obtained after morphological processing are not "properly filled". So I couldn't label them. One can crosscheck it by observing the segmented mask which is in binary image form**

[image]

```
    tic
clc;
clear all;
close all;
  
%read video file
video = VideoReader('D:\dvd\Matlab code\test videos\5.mp4');

T= video.NumberOfFrames  ;           %number of frames%

frameHeight = video.Height;          %frame height

frameWidth = video.Width ;           %frameWidth

get(video);                          %return graphics properties of video


i=1;

for t=300:15:550  %select frames between 300 to 550 with interval of 15 from the video  
    frame_x(:,:,:,i)= read(video, t); 
    frame_y=frame_x(:,:,:,i);

    %figure,
    %imshow(f1),title(['test frames :' num2str(i)]);
    frame_z=rgb2gray(frame_y);                 %convert each colour frame into gray
    
    frame_m(:,:,:,i)=frame_y; %Store colour frames in the frame_m array 
     
    %Perform Gaussian Filtering
    h1=(1/8)*(1/8)*[1 3 3 1]'*[1 3 3 1]  ;   % 4*4 Gaussian Kernel  
    convn=conv2(frame_z,h1,'same');
        
    g1=uint8(convn);
    
                    
    Filtered_Image_Array(:,:,i)=g1; %Store filtered images into an array
    i=i+1;
end

%Apply 3-D Fourier Transform on video sequences
f_transform=fftn(Filtered_Image_Array);

%Compute phase spectrum array from f_transform
phase_spectrum_array =exp(1j*angle(f_transform));

%Apply 3-D Inverse Fourier Transform on phase spectrum array and
%reconstruct the frames
reconstructed_frame_array=(ifftn(phase_spectrum_array));


k=i;

i=1;
for t=1:k-1
    
    %Smooth the reconstructed frame of Î(x, y, n) using the averaging filter.
    Reconstructed_frame_magnitude=abs(reconstructed_frame_array(:,:,t));  
    H = fspecial('disk',4);
    circular_avg(:,:,t) = imfilter(Reconstructed_frame_magnitude,H);
        
    
    %Convert the current frame into binary image using mean value as the threshold
    mean_value=mean2(circular_avg(:,:,t));  
    binary_frame = im2bw(circular_avg(:,:,t),1.6*mean_value);
    
    
    %Perform Morphological operations
    se = strel('square',3);
    morphological_closing = imclose(binary_frame,se); 
    morphological_closing=imclearborder(morphological_closing); %clear noise present at the borders of the frames
    
    
    %Superimpose segmented masks on it's respective frames to obtain moving
    %objects
    moving_object_frame = frame_m(:,:,:,i);
    moving_object_frame(morphological_closing) = 255;  
    figure,
    imshow(moving_object_frame,[]), title(['Moving objects in Frame :' num2str(i)]);
    
 i=i+1;
end
toc
```

Comment: You're not actually "tracking" any objects, only showing movement in the image. You'll need to introduce logic to label the connected movement "objects" and then track them from frame to frame using probabilistic labelling based on e.g. nearest position from the previous frame and velocity (be mindful of what happens if objects move near each other or cross paths).

Comment: @Hugh thanks for your feedback but could you guide me in below points

1. I am quite successful in capturing the moving objects( I.e. motion in the video). So is there any possibility **to detect single moving object** using the above algorithm?
2. if "**yes**" what changes should I have to make In the algorithm?

Comment: You need to label the connected objects, then you can track any number of objects you want. That is a big job and I will not write the code for you.

Comment: @Hugh sir,but I think labelling is not possible. because I am applying Fourier transform on **entire video signal** not on **"each frames individually one by one and then adding them afterwards""**.
Afterwards using **"phase only reconstruction"**,I am successful in detecting **whole motion part( all moving objects)** from the given video but not the single moving car.

Comment: If you are able to overlay the motion on the original video, you have already extracted the frame-by-frame information: you specifically state "10. Perform morphological processing, i.e., filling and closing, to obtain segmented mask of moving object for the current frame". Edit: What I am proposing is to do labelling on the reconstructed frame masks, not the DFT output.

Comment: @Hugh sir, I you have solved my above doubt. but there is another difficulty which I forgot tell you in the above comment. **2nd difficulty** is : after running the above MATLAB code, you will see that the **segmented frames** which I obtained after morphological processing **are not properly filled.so I couldn't label them. you can crosscheck it by observing the segmented mask which is in binary image form**

Comment: Well then you're going to have to fill them, aren't you?

Comment: @Hugh yes ,you are right. I tried so much to fill the vehicle shapes properly but I am not successful yet. I checked with different values  of morphological kernel  mask and different filter mask values .but could not get expected results.

Comment: Maybe you could fill them based on velocity direction - all "blobs" with the same velocity/acceleration that are within a threshold distance of each ther could be counted as the same?

Comment: @Hugh Nolan but this will arise questions like 
>1.  how to compute velocity of the blobs/ vehicle?
>2.  What should be done if 2 or more vehicles have same velocity?

Comment: There is no "right answer" here - you have to try and solve the problems to work "quite well" not "perfectly".